# SQL Like with double pipe concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with a SQL query that must match the username of a user out of a column that contains all the users usernames.

So the column will contain something like:

```
|USER1|USER2|USER3|USER11|USER22|
```

The user have pipes on the left and right to prevent "USER1" be matched even in "USER11".

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONCATUSERS LIKE ('%|' || 'USER1' || '|%')
```

Note that the USER1 in the query is a variable generated from our code so I must keep the concatenation syntax and I must use a standard syntax too (the code will run in mySQL, SQLServer etc..

So what is the correct way of concatenating strings in a LIKE clause?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server have different operators for string concatenation - which one specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I must use one that works for both and I've found that the double pipe should be the standard one

Comment: Unfortunately, despite it being a SQL "standard", it's not supported in SQL Server.  It is supported in MySQL but must be explicitly enabled.  SQL 2012 and later does support CONCAT so if you can constrain to that version then you _might_ be able to support both.

Comment: You should drop the idea of your code running in different flavors of SQL. While a simple `CONCAT` function is available in MySQL and SQLServer 2012 onward, there are a lot of syntax differences that you are going to run into with more complex queries and no matter how hard you hammer the square peg won't go into the round hole.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, the "standard" term tricked me as I thought a "standard" would be actually standard eheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/hh231515.aspx).
(available on SQL server 2012 and beyond)

It has the benefit that it implicitly converts types to add the value to the string.  And it's not just available on Sql Server and MySql.

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONCATUSERS LIKE CONCAT('%|','USER1','|%');
```

Do note that in MySQL the result will be NULL if one of the concatenated values is NULL.  But not on Sql Server.

It's just Oracle that's being stubborn by only allowing 2 values to that function.
So if the SQL needs to run unchanged on MySQL, a recent Sql Server AND Oracle then this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONCATUSERS LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%|','USER1'),'|%');
```

Comment: I would note that `CONCAT` is only supported by SQL Server 2012 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Noted. Yeah, one should always add such info when the tag isn't version specific.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses the double pipes for concat.  SQL Server you can use +.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE CONCATUSERS LIKE ('%' + '|user1|' + '%')
```

Comment: The problem is that I should use a standard syntax, not two different ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with CONCAT function.
As it is supported in both SQL and MySQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM xpat
WHERE plname LIKE concat('%' ,'|user1|' ,'%');
```

Comment: I would note that `CONCAT` is only supported by SQL Server 2012 and later.

Comment: user1 is a variable, this won't work.  If this worked the string constant `'%|user1|%'` would work.